# Django Will Not Pull CSS Static File (404 Error) Even Though File Paths Look Correct

Tags: django

When I load my local site I cannot get the CSS files to load. I'm running Django 1.9 and python 3.4.2.

Here is my structure:

```
apps/
    app1/
    app2/
    etc.
clients/
    media/ #css, js, images, etc.
    static/ #static files
    templates/ #html templates
__init__.py
manage.py
settings.py
etc.
```

In my settings.py file I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'clients', 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'clients/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'clients', 'media'),
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'clients', 'media')
```

And my html template that is calling the css files is as so:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/primary_stylesheet.css' %}" />
```

I continue to get a 404 error that says it can't find the css file in:/clients/static/css/primary_stylesheet.css

In my settings.py file I have printed out my STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT and they both lead directly where they should. I've read through the documentation and tried multiple variations of DIRS and ROOT and don't understand why the css file is not pulling correctly - even "collectstatic" is collecting correctly.

I greatly appreciate any help and wisdom someone else has to give.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the file `/clients/media/css/primary_stylesheet.css` exists? When you run `collectstatic` have you verified that `/clients/static/css/primary_stylesheet.css` exists?

Comment: Please add your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting as well.

Comment: @YPCrumble Yes I am sure that /clients/media/css/primary_stylehseets.css exists. And if I delete the CSS file from my /static/ file, and then collectstatic again, the file is properly updated in /static/css/

Comment: @YPCrumble Currently I have no STATICFILES_FINDERS setting listed...Is this a requirement?

Comment: What server are you using to serve this django application?

Comment: @th0th Just local server 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @Tarrant do you have `DEBUG=True` set? If you're on local that is all you should need _if_ like you said the static files are being properly collected to your `STATIC_ROOT` location.

Comment: @Tarrant do you have `"django.contrib.staticfiles"` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: @YPCrumble, yes Debug=True ; and yes I do have django.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APPS. Any changes I make to the files in my STATICFILES_DIRS always update in my STATIC_ROOT perfectly when I collectstatic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `DEBUG = True` set then django won't actually pull your files from the `/static/` folder - it finds and collects your staticfiles at runtime when you input the `runserver` command.

I think you'll find that if you use the default setting for `STATICFILES_FINDERS` your app will be able to serve your files:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added 'STATICFILES_FINDERS = [django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder,]' and my media files were still not loaded. I have not added '...AppDirectoriesFinder' to the array because I was under the impression that it would affect nothing because my staticfiles to be collected are not located inside of an app. I will try adding it this evening and see if anything changes...

Comment: @Tarrant would still have to be `STATICFILES_FINDERS` with the `S`.

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake - udpated!

Comment: yes for whatever reason adding 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder' to my STATICFILES_FINDERS array worked.Thank you for your help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your server with `python ./manage.py runserver`, you need to set urls for both `static` and `media` files, check here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

When I am starting a new project, I generally set my `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # your url patterns go here
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This requires you to set `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in your `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: I will try includin ga MEDIA_URL and add 'if setting.DEBUG:...' this evening and let you know if that fixes things.

Comment: FYI this did not fix the problem, but none the less I appreciate the url advice!